# Find rows matching any values in all specified groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables: `Attributes`,and `ItemAttributeValues` with the following structures.

**Attributes**

```
Id          Name
================
1           Color
2           Size
3           Occasion
4           Material
```

**ItemAttributeValues**

```
ItemId      AttributeId     Value           
=================================
A1          1               Green
A1          2               XL
A2          2               X
A3          1               Red
A3          3               Casual
A4          4               Linen
```

I have a stored procedure which accepts parameter named `@filters` a user defined table valued type having the following structure and sample values:

```
Name        Value
=================
Color       Green
Color       Red
Occasion    Casual
```

I want to find all the `ItemId` from `ItemAttributeValues` table matching atleast one value for each unique attribute in the filter. As seen in the sample values, attribute names(not ids) are provided so we will need to join the two tables.

In the above sample, those ItemIds having `Color` either `Red` or `Green` and `Occasion` having value `Casual` resulting in the following output:

```
ItemId
=======
A3
```

**Problem**:

I'm unable to formulate a sql logic encompassing the above criteria and I could use some help pointing in the right direction, especially for applying the logic of `Or` for the values and `And` for the Attributes. I'm using SQL server 2014.

Comment: Why the expect result only display `A3` instead of `A1` ,`A31` `A3`

Comment: The final result A3 is `ItemId`, the first column, not the value in the third column(Value). it is the only itemId that matches both attributes in filters, `Attr 1` and `Attr 3`. A relatable example will be like search in amazon for shirts Size:[XL,X], Color:[Blue,Green]. Should match both size and color, but any value given for each.

Comment: I updated the question with easy to understand values. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested all the scenario discuss with you.

It seem to work fine. Please throw your feedaback or Test scenario.

Try this,

```
declare @Attributes table(Id int,Name varchar(30))
insert into @Attributes VALUES
(1,'Color')
,(2,'Size')
,(3,'Occasion')
,(4,'Material')


declare @ItemAttributeValues table(ItemId varchar(30), 
AttributeId int, Value varchar(30))  

insert into @ItemAttributeValues VALUES
('A1',1,'Green')
,('A1',2,'XL')
,('A2',2,'X')
,('A3',1,'Red')
,('A3',3,'Casual')
,('A4',4,'Linen') -- ,('A3',4,'Linen')

declare @Filter table(Name varchar(30),Value varchar(30))

insert into @Filter VALUES
('Color',  'Green')
,('Color', 'Red')
,('Occasion','Casual')
--,('Material', 'Linen')
--,('Size','X')
--,('Size','XL')

Declare @DistinctFilterAttribute int

select   @DistinctFilterAttribute =count(distinct name) from @Filter
select @DistinctFilterAttribute

;With CTE as
(
SELECT IAV.*
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IAV.ItemId order by IAV.AttributeId )rn
from @Filter F
inner join @ItemAttributeValues IAV on F.Value=IAV.Value
)

select itemid from cte
where rn=@DistinctFilterAttribute
```

Now when requirement is clear, this is most optimized query,

```
select IAV.ItemId from @ItemAttributeValues IAV 
where exists(select 1 from @Filter F where F.Value=IAV.Value)
group by IAV.ItemId
having count(*)=@DistinctFilterAttribute
```

`@ItemAttributeValues`  appear to be very important table.
All 3 columns appear to be good candidate of index.
Since this appear to be dummy table structure nothing can be said.

Dependingg upon which column is most frequently use in `join/where` condition
Index can be created on those columns.

If it is possible to pass `Id` in filter table,though `Name` is not that bad.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't work either. What I'm after is that I have a filter with a list of attributes and multiple values for each attribute, need to match any one value for each attribute just like most online site searches filtering items based on features.

Comment: @MatJ,Can you give another example in your main question with 3 attribute and their values and desire output ?.I get back to you.

Comment: @MatJ, Suppose that you have ('Material','Linen') also in filter table.then wht is the output ?

Comment: no match, because each attribute should have a match. No item has all there attributes color,occasion and Material defined. To put it simply, for example: I need to find a T-shirt of size either x or xl(but no other size), and is (only) green color and is made of linen material.

Comment: Or a `formal` shirt, either blue or green (no other color), of size only X.

Comment: @MatJ,check my latest script and please don't forget to throw test scenario, if necessary.

Comment: This seems to work, I managed to rewrite it a bit with your query as base. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of row_number, I just grouped by itemid and used count(*)